# How to gain authentication using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Q1: I am new to tweepy and I am trying to gain an authentication for twitter data by using tweedy

```
import tweedy
consumer_key='....'
consumer_secret='....'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret,'https://twitter.com')
token = session.get('request_token')
session.delete('request_token')
auth.set_request_token(token[0], token[1])
```

the python is throwing error because it doesn't recognize the commands `session.get()` and `session.delete()`. 
Am I doing this right? Can someone show me how to gain authentication using tweepy please?

Q2. I know that I can create an instance of tweepy by executing `api = tweepy.API(auth)`
 providing that I executed `import twitter`, would `api.GetUser()` still work?

I already consulted the tweepy documentation but it is confusing me even more...

Thank you

Comment: Please show the actual error, rather than just saying that there is one.

Comment: Alos, show us where you found the code you presumably copied and pasted.

Comment: Finally, please don't try to cram two separate questions together into one. Especially since you can presumably try your second question out yourself to see if it works just as easily as anyone else can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's your actual code, you haven't defined anything named `session` anywhere, so presumably your error is something like this:

```
NameError: name 'session' is not defined
```

Since I have no idea what `session` is supposed to be in your code, it's hard to tell you how to fix it. Looking at the (presumably working) [examples](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/tree/master/examples) in the source tree, they don't seem to have anything similar to what you're trying to do.